# Why didn't Kreacher find Harry after Yaxley arrives at the house?

Tags: harry-potter, house-elves

I understand that Harry couldn't summon him because someone from the Ministry could have come along with Kreacher, but I don't understand why Kreacher couldn't find Harry because Dobby found Harry in *Chamber of Secrets*. And why *wouldn't* he want to find his master that he likes and is fond of now?

We know that Krecher doesn't stay at the house because he is found in Hogwarts during the battle. So my question is **why didn't he try to find Harry after Harry Ron and Hermione never returned?**

Comment: For the record it's not explicitly stated nor denied if Yaxley arrived at Grimmauld Place. We are just told to assume that he probably did.

Answer (score 6):

## Standing order: Work at Hogwarts

Harry, Ron, and Hermione failed to return to Grimmauld Place from the Ministry on September 2nd (*Deathly Hallows*, chapter 13), just as Hogwarts was resuming its busy school-year schedule.

Although Harry had called Kreacher away from Hogwarts — during the summer, when the workload for Hogwarts' kitchen staff was lower than normal — Harry had not countermanded the order he'd given Kreacher the previous year:

> "I want you to go to Hogwarts and work in the kitchens there with the
>   other house-elves."
>
> — *Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 3

When Harry gave that order, he'd had reason to mistrust Kreacher, and so had spoken sternly and forcefully.  In the absence of further instructions, the force of the order may have compelled Kreacher to resume his duties at Hogwarts.

Kreacher's newly-won loyalty may have similarly led him back to Hogwarts, as a way of honouring the last order Harry had given that Kreacher could still follow.

Comment: Good point. Since that was the last order he received ( apart from telling the story of the locket) and finding Mundungus which he already did. Kreacher would of switched to that order since the school year had started up again. But I still wonder why he wouldn't want to try and find his master whom he is fond of now... He goes to Cissy and Bella when ordered away by Sirius.. :/ @Gaultheria